# ReactJS : Should on express.js or some other middleware to handle login and sessions in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a react app from scratch which includes login and session handling.

The api's are all rest based and are already hosted on a server .
I just need to call the api's and validate tokens, maintain sessions and stuff.

How do i do it ?

Should i use some some midddleware like express for just the login part ? (I worked on someone else's react app and it was done in that way )

Or i can do it everything with just react ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```js
fetch(
            'http://localhost:4000/api',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(object to be sent on api) 
            }
        )
            .then(response => {
                if(response.status >=400){
                    // TODO proper error should be passed.
                    throw new Error('error');
                }
                 console.log(response.status)
                
                return response.json();
            })
            .catch(error => {
               console.log(error)
                return error
            })
        
        
    }
```

No need to use middle ware. Without middle ware you can do like provided above and call in a function and that function on some click or else your choice
you can do in react only and if you want to use middle ware do it with react-redux

Comment: if it worked for you, don't forget to accept to help others